# Javascript Addition operator Confusing & Not Working

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, addition

ok im trying to learn JS but its small thing like this that is making it hard and making me want to say just forget it

for example w3schools says A+=B is the same as saying A = A + B
but when i change this code around to NOT use the A+=B operand it and code it to work as A = A + B doesnt work the same!
so that means A+=B does NOT mean the same as A = A + B then!

heres w3chools example im learning "while" loops at moment and heres is my problem below and this is THEIR code it writes "The Number is 1-19" on a new line each time as it should

```
<h1>JavaScript while</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is MY Code Below and im basicall rewriting it from "A+=B to A = A + B" and it only writes "The Number is" ONE TIME and the number 1-19 on same line!

```
<h1>JavaScript while</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var text = "<br>The number is ";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        text = text + i;
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't understand loops.  You're overwriting `text` so *The number is* will only appear once by design, as expected.  If you want it to appear more than once, you need to have that portion in the loop.

Comment: In the first portion they are framing a string inside a loop and finally displaying the result, whereas in second your calculating the sum as number and displaying once at the last. Basically `text += "<br>The number is " + i;` concatenating string and `text = text + i;` is performing additino operation.

Comment: `a += b` certainly means `a = a + b`, the problem is that there's huge difference between the examples

Comment: The right conversion should be ==> text = text + "<br>The number is " + i;

Comment: first code is.....
if
TEXT="THE NUMBER IS  ";
I=0;

HOW IS....

TEXT = TEXT + I
Not the SAME as  TEXT += "THE NUMBER IS"  +  I

if TEXT="";
I=0;

?????
this is what confusing me is
A = A + B is same as A=+B
the code should still work if that was true

Comment: a+=b is same as a=a+b; which is perfectly fine. in your case b is not just b, it is  "<br>The number is " + i (including "+i" at the end)

Comment: Please write in international standard English, in which we capitalize the first word in a sentence, write the first-person pronoun as "I", and place periods (full stops) at the end of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between you code and `W3S`'s is that you add the `i` value to text each time not the desired text so the output would be `<br>The number is 123456789` to avoid that you should add `<br>The number is` every time:

```js
var text = '',
  text2 = ''
prefix = '<br>The number is',
  i = 0;
console.clear();

while (i < 10) {
  var toAppend = prefix + i
  text += toAppend;
  text2 = text2 + toAppend;
  i++;
}

document.write(text);
document.write('<br />*****************************');
document.write(text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the string each time in the loop:

```js
var text = "";
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  var curtext = document
    .getElementById("demo")
    .innerHTML;

  document
    .getElementById("demo")
    .innerHTML = curtext + "<br>The number is " + i;
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```